# With modern social networking and scaling, can Cassandra replace the standard relational database such as MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, cassandra, relational-database, key-value

Is it possible to build the entire social networking application on cassandra?
Sure, it takes longer to set up, but it scales much better.  Correct?

Please list the situations when Cassandra should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandra is in use at Digg, Facebook, Twitter, Reddit, Rackspace, Cloudkick, Cisco etc. so the answer to your first question would be yes.

The short version of the list that describes the situations in when Cassandra should be used.

- You need the possibility to add new
  nodes to yout cluster, with no downtime.
- You need a richer data model (column
  oriented) than simple key/value
- You need the possibility to have both
  synchronous and asynchronous
  replication for each update.

Answer (score 0):

yes, Cassandra is really highly used and showing its performance at Digg, Facebook, Twitter, Reddit, Rackspace, Cloudkick, Cisco etc. and its really scalable nosql database with a tiny code base and memory consumption so its will be really nice choice for big 24-7-365 web-projects and for reference you can see at

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/why-does-scalability-matter-and-how-does-cassandra-scale

http://www.slideshare.net/scode/scaling-with-apache-cassandra/

Comment: see also http://www.acunu.com/blogs/sean-owen/scaling-cassandra-and-mahout-hadoop/

Answer (score -2):

To briefly summarize [Brewer's CAP Theorem](http://www.julianbrowne.com/article/viewer/brewers-cap-theorem), your database is going to give you at most **two** of the following three properties:

- **Consistency**
- **Availability**
- **Partition Tolerance**

A relational database such as SQL Server or MySQL will give you consistency and sacrifices either availability or partition tolerance. A distributed database such as Cassandra will sacrifice consistency to give you both availability and partition tolerance.

So in short, use Cassandra if you don't need immediate consistency and are OK with [eventual consistency](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/12/eventually_consistent.html).

Comment: CAP applies equally to ANY database model. It does not imply that a RDBMS can't satisfy both availability and partition tolerance. There's nothing about the relational model that makes it unsuitable for a distributed, web scale application. In many ways the relational model is well suited for the kind of application under discussion. It's just that most standard SQL DBMSs don't provide good out of the box support for partitioning

Comment: Good clarification. Are you aware of any SQL DBMS's that sacrifice consistency for the sake of partitioning and availability by design?

Comment: I can't think of any SQL DBMS that forces consistency on you when you don't want it. If you don't require consistency between servers in a distributed system then you don't implement it that way.